# how to reroute in IIS so app think it is running from root

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

- I have my website running in /     (inprocess) (Blazor app)
- i have my API running in /API    (outofprocess) (asp.net.core)

all my routes already have API in them so my routes look like this:

```
xxxxxx.com/api/api/xxxx
```

is there anyway i can make my routes not use the folder the app is located in? inside IIS manager or in any of the web config files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understand your requirement clearly. Normally, if you hosted your API inside the API folder, the url you have provide is right.

If you just want to show the api in the url, I suggest you could consider using url rewrite.

It will rewrite the url from `xxxxxx.com/api/api/xxxx` to `xxxxxx.com/api/api/xxxx`.

More details about how to install it, you could refer to this [article](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite).

After installed it, you could add below config setting into your web.config file.

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
                    <rule name="RewriteAPI">
                        <match url="api/(.*)" />
                        <action type="Rewrite" url="http:///xxxxxx.com/api/{R:0}" />
                    </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```